# Saving SVM detector in float values

Tags: opencv, dlib

I used fhog_object_detector_ex.cpp to get SVM detector. In default, SVM output are serialized into `.svm` file. Is there a way to save those SVM trained data in float values into a file. So that I can load those coefficients into Opencv to test with HOGDescriptor's detect multiscale.
Thanks

Comment: dlib and opencv are not binary-compatible. but you can access trained object_detector instance and get its feature vectors.  object_detector::get_w() and processed_weight_vector::get_detect_argument() should help you here